# Unformat laptop windows drive using a bootable ubuntu usb stick

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, hard-drive-recovery, liveusb

I would like to recover the hard drive on my laptop which had windows 7 but was formatted.
 **Assuming I have an Ubuntu live usb stick, how can I unformat the laptop's drive?**

Notice I rather not open the laptop and extract the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a way to "unformat" a hard disk.  The data on it, depending on how it was formatted, could be lost forever.  There *may* be a way to recover the data (but likely not the boot sectors, if it's already been overwritten) if you consult a data recovery specialist.

Typically though, once a disk is formatted, there's no going back.  Be **very cautious** about when you want to next format your disk, and if you believe that the problem you're encountering now is only solvable by formatting, **make that your *last* resort.**

Answer (score 0):

You can not undo it completely.But you can recover some files from the hard drive by using the recovery software.

Here are informations to recover 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery